# When I use VS2010, I got an error creating a c++ project

Tags: visual-studio-2010

**An error occurred while creating or opening the C++ browsing database file r:/t1/t1.sdf. IntelliSense and browsing information will not be available for C++ projects.
Ensure that Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 is installed and that no other applications are accessing the file. If this problem persists, delete the file and reopen the solution.**

In a blog, the writer said that it's caused by the RAMDISK or FlashDisk, if use the harddisk, the problem will be solved. 
But i don't make, someone can help me?

Comment: May you need to re-install VS

Comment: thinks, but i have gotten this problem solved. i download the "SSCERuntime-ENU.exe" in Microsoft web page, and it worked. The error disappeared.

Comment: It's always good to indicate that the problem has been solved by marking one of the answers as the solution. In this case, since you yourself came up with it, feel free to add the answer to your own question and mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 21):

As [WhiteRabbit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1433648/whiterabbit) pointed out, download the "SSCERuntime-ENU.exe" from:

For VS2010:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=5783

For versions after VS2010:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=17876

Click download, then choose the suitable version for your device (`32-bit = x86`, `64-bit = x64`), then download and install it.

Comment: For the VS 2012 solution (Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0): http://microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876

Comment: Since he's new to the website, you should have let @WhiteRabbit know that he can mark his own answer as a working solution instead of rewriting his answer without providing any significant information to it.

Comment: For VS2013 it is also Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 instead.

Comment: Besides the warning, this answer actually solves the lagginess / poor response in VS2013 too.

Answer (score 5):

No amount of installing SQL Server Compact, repairing VS, etc. fixed this for me. Finally I saw something about a Network drive or RAM disk being unsuitable.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3a15f89c-074e-413c-ac6b-f8fceb64b7b1/how-do-i-enable-intellisense-to-work-on-a-ramdisk?forum=visualstudiogeneral

I assume that the database uses low level access to the file system that is incompatible with RAM disk or network drives, etc. The following setting moved the sdf file to a location that does not interfere with whatever direct access the database demands. After a VS restart the problem vanished.

tl;dr
**TOOLS / Options / Text Editor / C++ / Advanced / Always use fallback location = True**

Comment: This setting resolved the issue for me with Visual Studio 2012. It also made a bunch of ClearCase errors go away and is even a Microsoft-endorsed workaround in this situation: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/750401/