# An error occurred while creating and opening the C++ browsing database file

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, visual-c++, sql-server-ce, sql-server-2012

I am getting the following SQL Server compact Edition related error when I try to create a VC++ project in VS 2010. VS could not create it's default intellisence information file which ir [project_Name].sdf.

I tried to download the x86 and x64 versions of SQL Server Compact 3.5 & CE 4.0 and installed but that is not working. I tried with changing location of the project and its not working too. I am using windows 7 enterprise and VS 2010 professional SP1. Many thanks in advance.

Error = "An error occurred while creating and opening the C++ browsing database file.C:...fileName.sdf. IntelliSence and browsing information will not be available for C++ projects.

Ensure that Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 is installed and that no other applications are accessing the file. If the problem persists, delete the file and reopen the solution."

I have tried the solutions on the following links but no one worked :(

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/98f2441b-a50a-4d43-9200-9ca972d4ac86

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvc/thread/53e4b057-e0e2-42c6-9320-792bb7b82089

I have 
*Uninstalled and reinstalled both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 Service Pack
* Verified any existing .sdf is deleted

*Verified directory that .sdf is supposed to be written to is writable (I do see the .opensdf when it tries to create the sdf)

*Ran a repair of visual studio

*Uninstalled completely VS and Sql Server then reinstalled it.

None of this fixes the problem for me?   Please help me if anyone has any idea?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Be aware that your SDF file must not be located on a network drive!

Comment: The C# tag is wrong.
The question is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871608/when-i-use-vs2010-i-got-an-error-creating-a-c-project
For the VS 2012 solution (Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0): http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876